# How can I attach a new drain to a drain pipe that's fallen away from the tub?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drainage, drain-waste-vent

[image]

Hello everyone,

Noobie here and I think I shot myself in the foot!
I wanted to replace the old drain with a new one so my almost 2 year can have bubble baths. 
I was able to remove the old drain but ran into this issue.  The pipe sank in and I cant seem to screw on the new drain/old drain.  I've used a metal hanger to try and lift the pipe while attempting to screw on the drain and cant seem to do it.  Getting under the top isn't an option!  Suggestions!?!?

Comment: On the contrary, "getting under the top" is the **only** option. Wall repair is a given with many tub repairs, as there's rarely proper access without ripping a wall open.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you're in a spot of trouble. There's likely a nut around the flange of the waste pipe that you need to turn as you hold the drain flange in place.

If it's not possible to get behind the wall where the drain is, how about from below? Crawlspace / basement / first floor?

Even if you could get the threads started, you'd likely end up with leaks if you're spinning the drain flange- you want a thin bit of plumber's putty under the flange, and spinning the flange would likely lead to a broken seal and leaks.